# Oracle ORDS 22.1 Installation issue

Tags: java, database, jvm

I am trying to install Oracle ORDS 22.1 through Windows 10 cmd. When I run "java -jar ords.war" under the ORDS documents directory, the debugging info shows that the system no longer supports this command. What's more, it suggests I add ORDS to PATH to use ORDS commands. However, even if I set the path to the specified directory, "java -jar ords.war" still does not work.

What should I do to walk this around? Also, how to install ORDS 22.1 using Windows 10 cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ORDS folder to path will only allow you to run executable and batch files from that directory through cmd. To run the jar you still need to specify the full path to the jar file.

```
> java -jar C:\Users\user\folder\ords.war"
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. I have used the previous version of ORDS to sidestep this issue.

Comment: Since version 22.x of ORDS we do not run java -jar ords.war install, now: ords intall

Answer (score 0):

you need to type
`java -jar ords.war --config c:\ords_config_folder_address install`